# Finding $|a\bar{b}-b|$ equals

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $az^2+bz+1=0$ where $a,b,z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|a|=\frac{1}{2},$ have a root $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|=1$ . Then $|a\bar{b}-b|$ equals

Try: let other root is $\beta$. Then $$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a}$$ and  $$\alpha\beta=\frac{1}{a}$$

Now $\displaystyle |\alpha\beta|=\frac{1}{|a|}\Rightarrow |\beta|=2$.

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: (Not knowing the solution...) Suggestion: Try writing things in polar form: every complex number can be written as $re^{i\theta}$....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$a \,\alpha^2 + b \,\alpha + 1 = 0 \tag{1}$$

Multiply by $\,\bar a\,$ and use that $\,|a|=\dfrac{1}{2}\,$:

$$\dfrac{1}{4} \alpha^2 + \bar a b \,\alpha + \bar a=0$$

Take conjugates on both sides:

$$\dfrac{1}{4} \bar \alpha^2 + a \bar b \,\bar \alpha + a=0$$

Multiply by $\,\alpha^2\,$ and use that $\,|\alpha|=1\,$:

$$a \,\alpha^2 + a \bar b \,\alpha + \dfrac{1}{4} = 0 \tag{2}$$

Compare $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to solve for $b$.

Recall that for $w \in \mathbb{Z}$, $w \bar{w}$ can be written in a very nice way.